# A Macro to search a Word document for a string and change it to a hyperlink

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word, hyperlink

I have a Word macro that will search the Word document for a string and will then change it to a hyperlink. The issue I am having is I need to search the document for multiple strings and replace each with their own hyperlink. My macro will find the first string and put every hyperlink after the other. I figure it should be a simple fix to correct. As an example, I included only 2 of the 19 strings I need to change to hyperlinks. They will work individually, but not when all in a macro. This is a Word macro.

```
Sub Add_Hyperlinks()
'
' Add_Hyperlinks Macro
'
'
' Certified Water Professionals

    Dim linkText As String
    Dim link As String
    Dim foundsomething As Range
    
    linkText = "http://www.xxx.gov/cdphe/ccwp-certified-water-professionals"
    link = "http://www.xxx.gov/cdphe/ccwp-certified-water-professionals"
    
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "http://www.xxx.gov/cdphe/ccwp-certified-water-professionals"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With

    ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, Address:=link, SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:=linkText
    
' Compliance
    linkText = "https://wqcdcompliance.com"
    link = "https://wqcdcompliance.com"
    
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "https://wqcdcompliance.com"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute

    ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, Address:=link, SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:=linkText
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you intend this to run on a user-selected range in the document, or on the whole content?

Comment: The entire content. It is part of an automated letter generator from an Excel spreadsheet. There is text contained in cells on the Excel spreadsheet that are copied into the Word template. that contain the strings that are needing to be hyperlinks.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be optimal, since I'm totally not a Word VBA person, but it worked for me.

```vb
Sub Add_Hyperlinks()

    Dim doc As Document
    
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    
    Linkify doc, "http://www.xxx.gov/cdphe/ccwp-certified-water-professionals", _
                 "http://www.xxx.gov/cdphe/ccwp-certified-water-professionals"
    
    Linkify doc, "https://wqcdcompliance.com", _
                 "https://wqcdcompliance.com"
                 
    'etc for other links....
    
End Sub

'Find all instances of text `findWhat` in document `doc`, and
'  apply a hyperlink using URL `linkURL`
'Add a fourth parameter if you also need to control the link text. 
Sub Linkify(doc As Document, findWhat As String, linkURL As String)
    Dim rng As Range, col As New Collection, i As Long
    Set rng = doc.Range
    ResetFind rng.Find
    Do While rng.Find.Execute(findtext:=findWhat)
       ' `rng` is now the found text
       col.Add rng.Duplicate 'collect all found ranges
    Loop
    Debug.Print col.Count & " instances of '" & findWhat & "'"
    For i = col.Count To 1 Step -1 'link all found ranges
        doc.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=col(i), Address:=linkURL, _
          SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:=col(i).Text
    Next i
End Sub

Sub ResetFind(f As Find)
    With f
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Tim, very much appreciated. This is much more elegant and functional than the sledge hammer I was attempting to use. The only edit I needed to do on yours, was replace the "doc.Range.Find" in ResertFind sub with the "f" as passed to the subroutine.  I so much appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Missed that error - fixed above.  Glad it was useful.

Answer (score 1):

Please update `arrLinkText` and `arrLink` accordingly to incorporate all 19 strings (hyperlink).

- If `linkText` and `link` are always same, using one array is enough
- If `linkText` comes from Excel, it is easy to collect them from Excel with VBA code

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub AddHyperlinksToURLs()
    Dim rng As Range, i As Integer
    Dim arrLinkText, arrLink
    ' Update as need
    arrLinkText = Array("http://www.xxx.gov/cdphe/ccwp-certified-water-professionals", _
        "https://wqcdcompliance.com")
    arrLink = Array("http://www.xxx.gov/cdphe/ccwp-certified-water-professionals", _
        "https://wqcdcompliance.com")
    If UBound(arrLink) <> UBound(arrLinkText) Then
        MsgBox "Strings don't match with Hyperlinks."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set rng = ActiveDocument.Content
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrLink)
        With rng.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Text = arrLinkText(i)
            Do While .Execute
                If .Found Then
                    rng.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rng, Address:=arrLink(i)
                    rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                End If
            Loop
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```